# How to find files download link in network tab?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to find files download link in network tab but I don't know how to find download links.

I put a network tab picture below:

[image]

I would like to know how to do it with C# or Javascript.

Comment: why you want to do so?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj,I wanna download video transcript file.

Comment: Right click... open link in new tab... save tab as?